# R round values to 0.05 multiple

Tags: r, rounding, plyr

I have a data frame and I want to round all values to the closest 0.05 multiple.
I found out that the round_any from plyr could do this, but when I type the following code:

```
> library(plyr)
> round_any(Table, 0.05)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("round_any") : 
  no applicable method for 'round_any' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Could you please help me how I can overcome this?

Comment: Try `lapply(Table, round_any, 0.05)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as mentioned by the error message, is that you are trying to apply the function to a data frame, whereas it can only be applied to a numeric vector. If you apply it per column, it will work:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(Table, round_any, 0.05))
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!